# Impact of new "gtag.js" AdWords conversion tracking code on existing UA setup

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I got an email from Google requesting a change to my AdWords conversion tracking setup. They want me to add new library "gtag.js" and some calls to a "gtag" function.

This seems pretty easy. In my research, though, I've read some things that give me pause, e.g.

*"If you have Universal Analytics code on-page and are using any sort of customization to send events, virtual pageviews or other unique data to Analytics, you will likely not want to switch to gtag.js. That would mean updating all on-page customized code to the new gtag syntax. Not sure if you have custom code? Any use of custom dimensions, custom metrics, or events is likely relying on your current implantation of Universal Analytics."*

(Source: https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2018/01/30/guide-adwords-conversion-tracking-2018/)

I definitely have Universal Analytics calls in place; I'm not 100% sure what they mean by "on-page" (where else would they be?) but I suspect my stuff qualifies. As for "customization," I do make use of the numbered dimensions (e.g.  **ga('set', 'dimension4', creditStatusCode)** )

Does this really mean I should avoid gtag.js, though? I'm thinking not, but I'd also like to understand what that Bounteous.com post means.

One hunch I came up with is that the post is talking about sites that have actually made their own version of the UA script (i.e. modified analytics.js- I have not done this). Is that it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Global Site Tag for Google Ads conversion tracking without changing your current GA tracking setup at this point in time (though you would want to look at updating, once you have had a chance to check what needs to be ported over from Universal syntax to Global Site Tag).

If you were to only use gtag.js for google ads it would be similar to the following:

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google AdWords: GOOGLE_CONVERSION_ID -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-GOOGLE_CONVERSION_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-GOOGLE_CONVERSION_ID');
</script>
```

If you were to combine the GA and Google Ads tracking the snippet would be along the following line

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA-PROPERTY_ID"> 
</script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA-PROPERTY_ID');
  gtag('config', 'AW-GOOGLE_CONVERSION_ID');
</script>
```

Custom dimensions would need to be mapped in the GA config command
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

You would also need to update any event tracking to the gtag.js syntax, and same would apply to things like ecommerce tracking and so forth.

There is an analytics.js to gtag.js migration guide available
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration

Comment: Thank you. To be clear, am I correct in thinking that the first code snippet you posted is basically what I'd end up with if I took the less ambitious approach (i.e. leaving my current approach mostly in place, for now), and the second is what I'd end up with if I went all-out with the move to gtag.js? Or do I have it backwards?

Comment: The 2nd snippet is the base tracking code snippet for both GA and Adwords conversion tracking. It's a starting point..but it's not complete. You would also need to edit it to include the custom mapping for the custom dimensions and so forth. The first snippet is the less ambitious approach  for just the adwords conversion tracking without having to change your current GA tracking code setup.

Comment: OK, got it. I appreciate your help. So many dueling technologies, so little time...